# Why is setState value still empty after setting it to a certain value?

Tags: react-native

I am taking pictures with [`react-native-camera`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera) and saving  `data.uri` in state.

The first time the code is run, the state value is empty; on subsequent captures, the state value has the previous `data.uri` value.

It looks like other `setState` calls are behaving similarly (the value doesn't change after the first run, but it does change on subsequent clicks).

I am not very experienced with React Native - what might be causing this behavior?

[[image: takPicture function, setting state to setImageUri(data.uri)1]

[image: state keeping uri]

[image: logged console, image capature (setState(data.uri) is empty. But logging data.uri has a value]

[image: on another capture, imageCapture takes the value of the previous captureed state, difference can be seen when data.uri is logged along setImageState()]

**what am I not doing right? any help.**

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setImageUri`, you are scheduling an update to that component's state. However, `imageUri` is already assigned to the value that's currently in state *at the time of the current render*, and will not reflect the new value until the next render of your component. That's why you see an empty string the first time, and the "previous" value on subsequent calls.

So, it doesn't look like you are doing anything "wrong" per se, you're just misunderstanding what's happening when you update the state of your component.

If you want to see this in action, you could try [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

```js
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(`The current value of imageUri is: ${imageUri}`);
}, [imageUri]);
```

That will get called any time the value of `imageUri` changes.

Comment: how do I call takePicture function in useEffect , i get variable camera can't be found. I understand since takePicture takes variable camera when the camera is mounted. how do I go about this solution, any further tip?

Comment: You wouldn't call `takePicture` in `useEffect`, that was just meant to show that state actually _is_ getting updated, but not actually reflected in your `console.log` statement until the next render. If I were you, I'd read up on the link posted by Luka and make sure that you've got a solid understanding of React fundamentals: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get more familiar with the state in React.
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Setting the value is not synchronous task.

Comment: In your example just use data.uri insted of imageUri. imageUri will change but not instantly because React might wait for a bit to increase performance.